# jquery html() always changes content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I made a small cms where the frontend is based on jquery.
My problem is that sometimes in my module-template code 
i use something like this:

```
 <condition>

    </td></tr><tr>

</condition>
```

When i grap this template with jquerys html function:

```
var htmlString = $("#templateid").html();
```

jquery modifies the content in the condition tag.
The ouput is

```
 <condition>

</condition>
```

Its just works when the code in the condition tag is complete like

```
<table><tr><td></td></tr></table>
```

Is there any function where jquery outputs the html without modifying the content?

Comment: That is invalid HTML so is ignored.

Comment: Browser ignores that as rows that are not in a table can't be properly displayed. If you look at the resulting HTML with the browser inspector you'll see that it won't be there

Comment: Fix the HTML you generate, don't try to change other things to deal with that bug.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a [XY question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: .html() shouldnt change your html, and parts of your code are missing so it can't be debugged

Comment: +1: Although partial snippets *are not recommended*, they are sometimes a necessary evil. If it absolutely cannot be avoid, try the `script` block solution below. Otherwise refactor your code to use complete elements.

Answer (score 2):

Your HTML snippet is invalid, so is destroyed in a normal element.

*If you absolutely have to have a partial snippet* use a dummy script block instead, so it remains as text:

```
<script id="condition" type="text/template">

    </td></tr><tr>

</script>
```

Access with `$('#condition').html()` etc.

If you can, refactor your code to use complete elements. Then they can exist within other elements and not just inside script blocks.

Notes:

- Type `text/template` is an unrecognized type (I just use that one for my templates) so is just ignored by the browser.

Comment: -1 You're just helping him making his code *depend* on a bug that he should fix

Comment: @dystroy: As this is a valid answer *to the question asked*, your down-vote is not appreciated. It is not up to you to tell them how their templates must be created (suggestions are one thing). Partial snippets can happen.

Comment: When somebody finds it hard to jump to kill himself, is it appropriate to just push him ? No, I downvoted because you're making a big bug from a small bug.

Comment: @dystroy: With 144k rating, I would have expected a less critical approach to helping others :) feel free to post a better answer *to the question asked*.

Comment: You're **not helping**. Please read about the XY problem, you can even do that on meta.

Comment: @dystroy: Actually this is a very useful technique for providing potentially invalid or incomplete HTML. It is only your opinion to say it is not useful. I had added a an appropriate disclaimer for the retentive.